# What is WITH HEADER LINE used for in ABAP?

Tags: abap

I have been studying this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430248033) and quoting from it:

```
DATA: BEGIN OF CUSTOMER_TAB OCCURS 5,
         KUNNR TYPE KNA1-KUNNR,
         NAME1 TYPE KNA1-NAME1,
      END OF CUSTOMER_TAB.

This declaration creates an internal table and a structure using the same name: CUSTOMER_TAB.
```

And then in the following pages:

```
Declaring Both an Internal Table and a Structure by Referring to a Structured 
Local/Global TYPE or Local/Global Structure

DATA <internal table name> {TYPE|LIKE} <structure name> OCCURS <number> WITH HEADER LINE.

WITH HEADER LINE is a reserved key phrase. The addition of this phrase creates a structure.
```

I am confused at this moment. Is the first example declaring only an Internal Table or an Internal Table and a Structure with the same name?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question should be "What was WITH HEADER LINE used for in ABAP". You should see them only in legacy code. They are allowed only [outside classes](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/index.htm?file=abenitab_header_line.htm) and are [obsolete](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/index.htm?file=abenheader_line_glosry.htm) anyway.

Answering your question. It is both. It declares an internal table `customer_tab[]` and a structure `customer_tab`.

You could then do such "amazing" things like.

```
 LOOP AT customer_tab. "loops at tab CUSTOMER_TAB and stores current record in header line structure CUSTOMER_TAB. :]
   "do something with header line
 END LOOP.
```

or

```
 APPEND customer_tab.
```

As you see it is shorter and quite appealing to be used for its brevity. Though it is hardly readable and confusing, therefore marked as obsolete.

Oooops and one point more! You should also learn the difference between

```
CLEAR customer_tab.
```

and

```
REFRESH customer_tab.
```

Comment: But the first example does not have "WITH HEADER LINE", how is a Structure created as well?

Comment: In this case it is redundant I guess. If you look at the [documentation](http://help.sap.com/abapdocu_702/en/abapdata_begin_of_occurs.htm) of `BEGIN OF OCCURS` keyword you will see the following quote "This variant of the statement list introduced using DATA BEGIN OF (which is forbidden in classes) declares an internal table itab as a standard table with a structured row type and a header line.".

Comment: If you want to explicitly declare header line you could use it like this: `DATA: l_t_table TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF t000 WITH HEADER LINE.` Then the `WITH HEADER LINE` addition is not redundant. But do not do it in real life please. :)

Answer (score 3):

Both of the declarations you are showing, create a table with a header line. The first declaration does not specifically state 'WITH HEADER LINE', but it does create a work area and a table just as if you used the 'WITH HEADER LINE' statement too. See this [SAP Help](http://help.sap.com/saphelp_erp60_sp/helpdata/en/fc/eb36a1358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm) for information on header lines. The documentation you are referencing is obsolete syntax. You will see it due to legacy code, so you need to understand it but avoid using this syntax.

Comment: What is the syntax for creating a table WITHOUT header line?

Comment: For example `DATA: l_t_table TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF t000`. This creates a standard table without header line, so for example to loop through it you would need to use a field symbol.

Answer (score 0):

```
types:
  begin of typ_functions,
  funcname type rs38l_fnam,
  pname    type pname,
  fmode    type fmode,
  stext    type rs38l_ftxt,
  end of typ_functions,
  typ_functions_t type standard table of typ_functions initial size 0.

  data:   
           "Global Structure using structure type
           gs_function   type typ_functions,   
           "Global Table using table type typ_functions_t
           gt_functions  type typ_functions_t,
           "Global Table using data dictionary structure
           gt_exp        type standard table of rsdsexpr initial size 0.
```

My personal preference is to use syntax as shown above, in TYPES, I've created the structure type and table type. Then in DATA, I'll create the actual table and structure. In the example, I declare a global structure and table.  For just declaring a table from a data dictionary reference, I use the declaration shown as GT_EXP.  The inline comments are only for this discussion, I dont use this format in a program per se.