# Difference between Internal Table declarations OCCURS and TYPE TABLE OF?

Tags: abap, internal-tables

And which one should be preferred / why?

So I have a TYPE defined locally:

```
TYPES:
    BEGIN OF CUSTOMER_STRU_TYPE,
        KUNNR TYPE KNA1-KUNNR,
        NAME1 TYPE KNA1-NAME1,
    END OF CUSTOMER_STRU_TYPE.
```

and I think these 2 statements seen below will both do the same thing:

```
DATA:
    CUSTOMER_TAB TYPE CUSTOMER_STRU_TYPE OCCURS 5.

DATA:
    CUSTOMER_TAB TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF CUSTOMER_STRU_TYPE.
```

Are there any differences between the 2 statements seen above and which one should be preferred?

Comment: You have already asked about it. The first statement with `OCCURS` defines an internal table with header line, the other defines an internal table without header line. `OCCURS 5` means that initially there will be assigned memory for 5 rows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is WITH HEADER LINE used for in ABAP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36282951/what-is-with-header-line-used-for-in-abap)

Comment: Hi @Jagger . The difference between those 2 are: the existing / lack of: STANDARD TABLE OF not "WITH HEADER LINE".. This is a different question actually.

Comment: With all due respect I disagree. :) Especially that I mentioned about `STANDARD TABLE OF WITH HEADER LINE` in one of the comments there.

Comment: @Jagger Well ok, you are probably right. I am very new to SAP / ABAP so I am still trying to understand. I think it will make sense with time, I am just confused at the moment. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference between the two statements is that, in the first one you're reserving memory space for storing 5 lines of customer_tab table.
In terms of performance, the best statement is the second one.

Comment: The first statement also declares a "header line" in addition to the table, thus when you try to access the table you have to explicitly state that you want the table using square brackets ( eg. CUSTOMER_STRU_TYPE[] ).