# "MOVE" works for literal but doesn't for internal table

Tags: abap

I am working on automation reports in SAP and I can't input the value of `gt_output3-namev` to `gt_output-namev01`.

It works when I move only a string literal ('1' is set).

It doesn't work when I move `gt_output3-namev` (remains empty).

How can I fix that? Thanks

I tried debugging and I can see the value from `gt_output3-namev` is not written in `gt_output-namev01`.

```
SELECT
      knvk~lifnr, knvk~namev, knvk~name1, knvk~titel_ap, knvk~telf1, knvk~abtnr
    FROM knvk
    WHERE  knvk~lifnr = @lv_lifnr AND knvk~abtnr = '0002'
    INTO TABLE @gt_output3.

  IF sy-subrc = '0'.
    MOVE gt_output3-namev TO gt_output-namev01. ---> doesn't work
    MOVE '1' TO gt_output-name101. ---> works
    MOVE '1' TO gt_output-titel_ap01.
    MOVE '1' TO gt_output-telf101.
    MOVE '1' TO gt_output-smtp_addr01.
  ENDIF.

  APPEND gt_output TO gt_final.
```

Comment: Do... not... use `MOVE` anymore unless you are on a very, very old SAP system (ex. R/3). Well... in fact... do not use it even there.

Comment: You are using an internal table with a **header line**, this has been flagged **obsolete** because it was prone to errors, exactly the issue you are experiencing: you think you are working with the actual data from the internal table, but you are using the header line that you didn't initialize yet.

Answer (score 3):

## `gt_output3` is a [table with header line](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abenitab_header_line.htm)

This means you have a table and a structure with the same name. [It is quite convenient, but obsolete now](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36282951/2354702), as it led to many confusions.

It contains values *as a table* because of the SELECT, but in your case `gt_output3` was never given value *as a structure*. This causes the problem with the `MOVE` (note: Moves are obsolete now too, use `=` instead):

```
MOVE gt_output3-namev TO gt_output-namev01.
```

You can get the values of `gt_output3` by LOOPing through the table for example:

```
LOOP AT gt_output3 ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_output3>). 
  gt_output-namev01 = <ls_output3>-namev.
```

Caution: `gt_output` is considered here as a structure, not as an internal table (which is wrongly guessed from its naming convention). Probably you have defined it also as an internal table with a header line, so better remove the header line and declare/work with a separate structured variable (`data gs_output like line of gt_output` and `gs_output-namev01 ...` for instance).

If you have ABAP 740 or newer, you can access rows directly by row number, for example to access the first row:

```
gt_output-namev01 = gt_output3[ 1 ]-namev.
```

Comment: I think it's worth adding an explanation about **header lines** (obsolete), so the OP should change its internal table declaration. You shouldn't use **MOVE**, it's also obsolete.

Comment: There is a nice question regarding tables with header line [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36282951/what-is-with-header-line-used-for-in-abap)

Comment: It´s both, table and structure. Anyway it´s works so thanks a lot guys. Also i will look into link and will try not to use move.

Comment: It's certain that `gt_output3` is an internal table with a header line because we can deduce from the question that the code compiles, that gt_output3 is an internal table (`INTO TABLE @gt_output3`) and that it's also a structure (`gt_output3-namev`).

Comment: @s3t4m about "anyway it's works" : "[stackexchange is a network of Q & A forums, not help forums](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th), so it matters to improve the quality of both questions and answers at any time ;-)

Comment: Almost perfect, thanks. I propose this other version, I let you check the differences, feel free to revert back to your text.

Comment: @SandraRossi this one is better